# Getting the name of a variable in Java

Tags: java, introspection

Is it possible to get the name of a variable in Java at runtime?

Possible use case: in assertions. Given an assertion like

```
assert percval >= 0 && percval <= 100 : "percval out of range: " + percval;
```

Depending on your IDE, if you refactor the code, rename the variable, it may not automatically change occurrences in strings. Possible result:

```
assert percentage >= 0 && percentage <= 100 : "percval out of range: " + percentage;
```

Would be nice if there was something like this:

```
assert percval >= 0 && percval <= 100 : nameOf(percval) + " out of range: " + percval;
```

Possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible in java. Reflection might get you the name of members, but not local variables.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print the variable name holding an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959206/how-do-i-print-the-variable-name-holding-an-object)

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? I am curious because I did not use it self and wonder if it is possible with I have given link to ?

Comment: I didn’t try it either since the project still develops on Java 7 only. If it works, it would be what I was looking for. I will come to it later when switching to Java 8. I do not know when this will happen.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it was possible before java 8 but with java 8, you can follow the [following link](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118) and achieve what you want to do.

The summary of this is given as follows;

> Provide a mechanism to easily and reliably retrieve the parameter
>   names of methods and constructors at runtime via core reflection.