# With a PANDAS dataframe, how do I print out the variable name along with the data inside it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

Using the Python package PANDAS, I have a simple loop where I want to print some data frame information

```
for df in (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7):
    print(df.keys())
```

However, I also want to label each dataframe with its variable name (ex: df1 or df2). Is there a way to print the variable name?

Looking at [How do I print the variable name holding an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959206/how-do-i-print-the-variable-name-holding-an-object) there doesn't seem to be a good answer for java but I'm not sure with Python. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Are they always named by "df" and the numbers from 1 to n? In this case you could use enumerate to iterate and print df with the proper index.

Comment: Store the dataframes in a dictionary rather than a tuple: `dict_frames = {f'df{i}':df for i,df in enumerate([df0, df1, df2, . . . ])}`

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, adding a =  in an f-string like so print(f"{df =}")

Comment: This is not possible, objects are not aware of the names that point to them. Also they can have more than one, or none.

Comment: @Tobotis I just named it that way for this example but every df have a different name based on letters

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zip() to iterate over two lists simultaneously.

```
dfs=[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7]
dfs_names=['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7']

for name, df in zip(dfs_names, dfs):
  print(n ,df.keys())
```